Resizing selection leaves background gap
I'm a complete noob at this stuff, so apologies in advance.
I'm trying to resize just the letter C in  .dds file, so that I can change into a Ç later. Rescaling it with the alpha channel locked gives me . Problem is, I can't fill in the gap with the background color (in fact, I can't even color pick the background). Please help.

You have a floating selection. You need to anchor it somewhere at some point. Probably best if you anchor it to its own layer. If you can't still fill the area, then you need to do Layer > Layer to Image size.  BTW I wouldn't use GIMP for an icon like this.  Better to use vector software such as Inkscape.
